# Can group same parameters in url string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
let data = {
    name: "title",
    rooms: "01",
    array: [1,2,3],
    city:"cityName"
}
let param = (({ name, rooms, array, city }) => ({ name, rooms, array, city }))(data);
let url = $.param(param);
let stringCut = "%5B%5D"
let queryString = url.split(stringCut).join("");
window.location.href = `/country/city?${queryString}`;
```

result:
"http://localhost:10000/country/city?name=title&array=1&array=2&array=3&rooms=01&city=cityname"

It work well but If array have multiple item so error "The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long."

It can set maxQueryString to big number to resolved this problem.
Have other solution?

Thank so much.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but you should look to do it at the point the URL is created, not by hacking the querystring around in an intermediary/receiving page. As such can you please edit the question to include details of the code which creates this querystring

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I guess the questioner wants also to know how.^^

Comment: @Reporter well yes, but that entirely depends on how the querystring is created, which is why I asked for more details in the original comment.

Comment: Please aware of HTTP Parameter Pollution attacks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I have added more details. This problem also resolved by increase maxQueryString in web.config. Thank you so much. <3

Comment: No problem, glad you got it resolved.

Comment: I had another problem when I deployed the code to azure, the web.config file was replaced, so it lost the maxQueryString setting. I want web.config not to be replaced every time I deploy. Anyone help me? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question about that as this one is tagged with JS/jQuery, so it's unlikely to attract the attention of anyone who knows about ASP.Net or Azure configuration.